# Rails 4 - Retaining Form values on refresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a Rails 4 ecommerce app. On the order page, when collecting address info, I have a state dropdown using a helper method that lists US States.

```
<%= f.select(:state, options_for_select(us_states), {prompt: "Select"}, {class: "form-control"}) %>
```

When the user has an error in the form - say the credit card number is entered wrong, when the page refreshes with the error message, the state dropdown autoselcts "Alabama" since that is the first state listed in the dropdown.

Is there a option I can use which will retain the previously selected state?

Note: all the other info like address, etc is retained. Just the state dropdown is not retained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retain previous state as:

```
<%= f.select(:state, options_for_select(us_states, f.object.state_id), {prompt: "Select"}, {class: "form-control"}) %>
```

I assume you have an association defined for your model and so, also a foreign key `state_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using f.select_tag instead of f.select